# Sony Vaio Pro 13 ultrabook- powerful enough to run VS2012?

Tags: laptop, cpu, visual-studio, ultrabook

I am thinking of purchasing a Sony Vaio Pro 13 Ultrabook. The specs would be:

- **Intel i5-4200U @ 1.6GHz**
- 8GB RAM
- 256GB SSD

http://www.sony.co.uk/product/vn-pro

All the reviews I have read mention "web browsing is fine" - which you would expect - but none of the reviews (obviously) test VS2012.

Would someone be able to comment on how capable the processor would be for developing in Visual Studio 2012? I think the battery life would be good- I am worried about raw CPU performance when running programs.

My laptop has an i7 620M @ 2.66GHz- which is 3 years old now, but it runs VS2012 absolutely fine - so I'm not sure if I can assume the Haswell mobile CPU would be of similar performance to my current CPU.

Comment: This is asking for opinions and I suspect will be closed.

Comment: Not really- either the CPU can run VS2012 fine or it can't...... either the undervolted Haswell CPU is as powerful as my Nehalem i7 or its not....

Comment: @mezamorphic I would not call going from 2.66ghz to 1.6ghz and upgrade it is the reverse a downgrade.  Going from a core i7 2.66Ghz is going to definitely be faster than a core i5 @ 1.6ghz. Almost anything will run VS2012, but it maybe slow.  Unless your programs are all small the core i7 you have is faster.  Buy an SSD for you Core i7 and call it done.

Comment: @cybernard I was upgrading in terms of laptop weight- so long as the laptop run VS2012 i'm not too worried about performance. I was gonna get 8GB ram and an SSD with the laptop.

Comment: @cybernard the base clock speed is not an indicator for performance. in fact both CPUs perform almost exactly the same: http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Core-i7-620M-vs-Intel-Core-i5-4200U

Comment: Did you buy it? Did you like it as dev machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will run perfectly fine.
I have an i5 3337u 1.8ghz, 2gb ssd, 4gb RAM.(The ssd isnt much of a factor)
I have VS2012 and SQL Server 2012 installed which are running PERFECTLY fine even when both are run at the same time!
Go ahead and buy.
Good Luck!

Comment: I just looked at my current i7 620M and I have it under-volted running at 1.2GHz!